# 500 Internal Server Error on trying to install

Tags: install, error, apache

Probably something really silly I'm missing here but I'm trying to test out Craft with a look at purchasing but can't even get to a first step in installing it :-(

As far as I can tell the server requirements are all covered. All files have been uploaded to FTP although I have my **domain.com** and then a **craftcms** folder then within that folder I have the **craft** and **public** folders.

I have had to do things like this as can't place craft as the main folder on the server due to the server already having a site on it although I'm fairly certain I should be able to run the craft site in this way shouldn't I? From a sub-folder I mean.

Anyway when I go to **domain.com/craftcms/admin** I get an Apache 500 Internal Server Error and not really much more information. I have also tried going to the alternative admin URLs to see if one of those works and they all come up with the same error.

Just wondering if I'm missing something obvious here?

Many thanks in advance.

Best wishes,

Mark

Comment: What's installed on the root domain? Another script maybe? Also be careful to check the .htaccess file there...

Comment: Hmm seems I was getting mixed up with the URL I should visit.

I was going to **domain.com/craftcms/craft/admin** but I actually needed to go to **domain.com/craftcms/public/admin**.

I could swear from reading the docs that it seemed that I was doing the right thing but I can only get the **Begin** button to come up with that second URL so I'm guessing that's correct?

Comment: Btw, why don't you install it on a subdomain? That'll make it slightly less confusing

Comment: Definitely a good idea. Will take a look at perhaps doing that.

Comment: All working much better now as have placed the craft folder above the htdocs folder and have the contents of the public folder in htdocs. All works beautifully and have set it up as craft.dev so I can try out the Pro version. Also got my computer working as a proxy server so I can view and edit the site from my iPhone / iPad. Just need to get my head completely around the way things work as opposed to in ExpressionEngine. Just need that light bulb moment.